# Is there a "URL Queue" app that you exports an RSS feed?

Tags: rss

I'd like an app / browser plugin that saves items for reading later, and can be consumed via subscribing to an RSS feed.

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ReadItLater](http://readitlaterlist.com/) - it has browser plugins or bookmarklets for all major browsers and can be consumed by plenty of readers and mobile applications.